# C# Nullable Explicit cast required

Tags: c#

```
    private bool? _success;
    public bool Success
    {
        get
        {
            return _success ?? (_success = false);
        }
    }
```

Why can't the compiler figure out the right operand is always false, and requires me to cast it to `bool`?

Comment: Note that if you're never reading `_success` directly, you may wish to consider just using an auto-property for `Success` and scrapping `_success` (with `private set`).  `bool` does default to `false`.  Of course, this is only OK if there are no private implementation details which givemeaning to `_success` being `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right operand is a `Nullable<bool>` since you're assigning to `bool? _success`.  This can't be implicitly cast to a bool, which is why the cast is required.

If you remove the assignment, then it will work fine:

```
return _success ?? false;
```

This works as the "false" is a `bool` already.

However, your current code returns `_success` after assigning it a value of `false`.  `As _success` is a `bool?`, the right hand operand is returning `bool?`, and not `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

You would ordinarily write this using `GetValueOrDefault()`:

```
private bool? _success;

public bool Success
{
    get
    {
        return _success.GetValueOrDefault(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second won't compile - it has the same issue.  The first works, but has different logic (as it's not *assigning* `_success` to `false` anymore.  (I agree, however, that it's a more common usage...)

Answer (score 0):

From C# 8.0 and upwards, you can use the [null-coalescing assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#null-coalescing-assignment) `??=`, and write most concisely:

```
private bool? _success;
public bool Success => _success ??= false;
```

The compiler will evaluate the expression as a whole and respect that the right-hand side matches the required `bool` type.